# Regex match the double quote in BBCode attribute

Tags: php, regex, bbcode, phpbb3

I have text stored in my [phpbb3](/questions/tagged/phpbb3) forum database with some incompatible [bbcode](/questions/tagged/bbcode) such as the following:

```
Some text with [COLOR="red"]colored text[/COLOR] and [SIZE="7"]Big fonts[/SIZE] while "This double quote" is not matched
```

What I want is a regex that match any double quotes `" "` with any string inside them while those double quotes are inside the square bracket `[ ]` of the bbcode.

I need this to be able to fix those bbcodes by stripping  the double quotes. The regex implementation is going to be using PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be looking for something like this:

```
$code= 'Some text with [COLOR="red"]colored text[/COLOR] and [SIZE="7"]Big fonts[/SIZE] while "This double quote" is not matched';

preg_match_all('/\[.*?="(\w+)"\]/', $code, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches[1]); $i++) {
    echo $matches[1][$i]."\n";
}
```

***DEMO:***
https://ideone.com/LEZHgx

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
\[\w+=("[^"]*")\]
```

It matches square bracket, alphanumerics, equal sign, quoted string, close square bracket. Capture group 1 will contain the quoted part.

Comment: I need the quotes inside the bbcode square brackets not all the brackets.

Comment: Use a capture group to extract the part you care about. Or use lookarounds.